# curl HTTPS via an SSH proxy

Tags: curl, ssh, proxy

I want the below curl command to run from my machine, but via a remote proxy server.

> curl "https://site.fake/ping"

However, I want this to always work via a remote proxy server.

I was tring to set this up with an ssh tunnel:

```
sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key_file -L 443:site.com:443 username@remote.proxy.com
```

But this did not do the trick, running under osx.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using a `socks5` proxy for example:

```
$ ssh -D 8080 -f -C -q -N user@remote.host
```

- -D 8080 tells ssh to launch a SOCKS server on port 8080 locally.
- -f Forks the process to the background.
- -C Compresses the data before sending it.
- -q  Uses quiet mode.
- -N Tells SSH that no command will be sent once the tunnel is up.

Then you could use `curl` like this:

```
curl -x socks5h://0:8080 https://example.com
```

Comment: Pretty awesome. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for explaining each parameter as well.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks

Comment: this works amazing! Thanks! How can I stop the server though?

Comment: you could run `ssh -O exit user@remote.host` that will terminate the ssh session